# Scrapy handling session cookie or 302 in asp.net site

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a web application written in asp.net.

I am trying to execute a search and crawl the search results page. Lets say that the search page is http://search.site.com/search/search.aspx

Now my crawler is pretty straight forward

```
class SitesearchSpider(Spider):
    name = 'sitecrawl'
    allowed_domains = ['search.site.org']
    start_urls = [
        "http://search.site.org/Search/Search.aspx"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
        self.log("Calling Parse Method", level=log.INFO)
        response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace("disabled",""))
        return [FormRequest(
            url="http://search.site.org/Search/Search.aspx",
            formdata={'ctl00$phContent$ucUnifiedSearch$txtIndvl': '2441386'},            
            callback=self.after_search)]

    def after_search(self, response):
        self.log("In after search", level=log.INFO)
        if "To begin your search" in response.body:
            self.log("unable to get result")            
        else:
            self.log(response.body)
```

But no matter what the same page (search.aspx) is only returned to the after_search callback instead of the expected searchresults.aspx with the results

This is what seems to happen in the browser

1. Search term is entered in one of the fields
2. Search button is clicked
3. On form submit to the same page (search.aspx) i see that it returns a 302 redirect to the search results page
4. The search results page then displays
5. I see that the asp.net session cookie is being used here because once a search is made, i can take the search results page URL something like
   http://search.site.com/search/searchresults.aspx?key=searchkey&anothersearchparam=12 and open any tabs and the results load directly
6. If i open a new session and paste the URL then i am getting redirected to the search page

Now i went through the docs and I am not sure if I have to deal with the 302 or the aspnet session cookie. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to deal with 302, scrapy does itselr.
2. You can debug cookie, set DEBUG_COOKIE = 1 on settings
3. Did you check that what other params are send in post or get method when you search from browser, you have to pass them all in form data.

I suggest you to use fron _response, like:

```
return [FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'ctl00$phContent$ucUnifiedSearch$txtIndvl': '2441386'},
```